# Can words in Spanish in tags be properly spelled?

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, estado-planificado

I like the site having tags in Spanish, but my eyes bleed when I see all accents are missing (and I imagine that *diéresis* also). Can tags written in Spanish be written as they should (with accents)?

Comment: This feature is already [asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135929/add-non-latin-character-set-support-for-tags) in MSO.

Comment: We're planning on adding unicode support in tags. It's currently turned on for [russian.se] and [japanese.se].

Answer (score 1):

No, accents and diacratic marks are stripped from tags on the SE network.

If you want this changed, I suggest posting a feature request on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).  I suspect it won't be done, but it wouldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Then I don't like Spanish tags anymore ;-) If we are a site for the correct usage, then we should be careful regarding every aspect, including spelling, and badly spelled tags might produce an undesired side-effect on people starting to learn English.

Comment: You can see a [related feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135142/165502) I posted, which has already been completed. So maybe they'd be willing to support diacratic marks in tags (I would vote for it if you post the request).